# web based service for tracking disparate forum posts

Tags: service, forum, tracker

Any one know of a web based service that will track my user name/password combinations for the many forum sites that I use and aggregate all of my posts on each of these disparate sites into a single web based dashboard?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool which would probably be extraordinarily difficult to write given how many varied ways forums have been implemented. This will probably be easier when Web 3.0 (whatever and whenever that might be) is real.

Comment: I see there is support on stackoverflow for RSS feeds. Perhaps someone knows of a good program to aggregate RSS feeds? How do I request feeds for just posts I've submitted on stackOverlow?